# How to have alternate colors in alternate rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to do this hands-on project where I am not able to code alternate colors for rows as per the image attached below. There are total of seven rows and I need `white` and `grey` as alternate colors. I went through few documentation but was unable to do so, below is my `HTML` and `CSS` code.

`HTML`
`I have seven rows as such`

```
<!-------- [![enter image description here][1]][1]Row 1 ---------->
<div class="container">
      <div id="main-container">
        <div>
            <h1>10.99</h1>
            <p>UDS/DAY</p>
            <br>
            <button>SELECT</button>
            <br>
            <P>Total 76.93 USD</P>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/vehicles/car1.gif" />
            <p>Extra Small Car</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p><img src="./images/icon_man.gif">x 4 Passengers</p>
            <p><img src="./images/icon_sm_scase.gif">x 2 Small Suitcases</p>
            <p><img src="./images/icon_lg_scase.gif">x 0 Large Suitcases</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Automatic transmission</p>
            <p>Air Conditioning</p>
            <p>24 miles/gallon</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`
`This is my entire CSS`

```
.container{
  margin-top: 1%;
}
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(248, 246, 246);
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 65%;
  font-size: 2.vmin;
}
#main-container > div > img {
  width: 100%;
}
#main-container > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 15%;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 25%;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 30%;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 30%;
}
#main-container div {
  align-items: center;
  width: 65%;
}
#main-container button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #117CC0;
  border: none;
  height: 38px;
  width: 90px;
}

#main-container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25PX;
}
p, h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

If someone can please help me with how to do it and make me in understanding the logic

Comment: by row do you mean the `div`s inside the main container? or the `main-container` is one row...there are 6 more like `main-container`?

Comment: Please check your question - the image is not added correctly and I think it would help us understand what you mean by 'a row'. It may also help if you could make your code into a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wanna try to add the following lines to the css like so. the pseudo-class counts the elements in the container and alternates as demanded.

```
#main-container div:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ccc;
}

#main-container div:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

you can as well alternate the p, then just change it where it says div, but make sure the elements are in the "alternating container".

Comment: Hello`tensaigrfx`, your code does work but its alternating vertically and I need `horizontally` , can you please suggest how to do it

Comment: I already wrote, see under the code, hence your html needs changes as all the p are alternated, which you don't want I suppose.

you can use a class eg. p.alternates.

without a picture of the design it is rather difficult to determine your wishes.

Comment: Thank you `tensaigrfx` for the help  and I'll try fixing it as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.container{
  margin-top: 1%;
}
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(248, 246, 246);
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 65%;
  font-size: 2.vmin;
}
#main-container > div > img {
  width: 100%;
}
#main-container > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 15%;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 25%;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 30%;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 30%;
}
#main-container div {
  align-items: center;
  width: 65%;
}
#main-container button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #117CC0;
  border: none;
  height: 38px;
  width: 90px;
}

#main-container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25PX;
}
p, h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
#main-container div:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ccc;
}

#main-container div:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
   

<div class="container">
      <div id="main-container">
        <div>
            <h1>10.99</h1>
            <p>UDS/DAY</p>
            <br>
            <button>SELECT</button>
            <br>
            <P>Total 76.93 USD</P>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/vehicles/car1.gif" />
            <p>Extra Small Car</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p><img src="./images/icon_man.gif">x 4 Passengers</p>
            <p><img src="./images/icon_sm_scase.gif">x 2 Small Suitcases</p>
            <p><img src="./images/icon_lg_scase.gif">x 0 Large Suitcases</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Automatic transmission</p>
            <p>Air Conditioning</p>
            <p>24 miles/gallon</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```